# Jersey 2 - centralized link resolver

Tags: java, rest, hyperlink, jersey-2.0

At work, we serve many REST API and our codebase has grown in quite an organic way.
We mainly serve ATOM+XML with `rome:rome:1.0` artefact. Therefore, all our resources methods return a `SyndFeed`.

The main problem we encounter with Jersey 2 (that we also had, before upgrading, with Jersey 1.x) is we have not yet found a way to separate concerns between serving contents (responsability of a Resource) and creating these *hyperlinked* contents (responsability of our business layer + a resolver *yet to determine*).

Right now, each resource is responsible for:

1. mapping our business objects to their `SyndFeed` representation
2. and therefore, resolving all self/related/inline links is also done by the resource directly

Point 2 is currently achieved via Jersey-managed `UriInfo` (via `@Context`) from which derive many garbage URI resolver methods defined in a common Resource superclass.

`UriInfo` is currently needed for its `getBaseUriBuilder()` method, allowing us to construct paths.

Because `UriInfo` is a Jersey-managed bean, there is no way to extract all those URI resolver methods into one or several standalone resolvers.
Because of this limitation, there is currently no way to extract the hyperlinked contents creation out of the resource classes (instead: a garbage Resource superclass that will always grow).

As of now, you might think about the [declarative hyperlinking feature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/declarative-linking.html) of Jersey 2.
However, as far as I understand the docs, this feature won't work in my context. Indeed, `@InjectLink` can only be used by Resource result beans and our resource return only instances of `SyndFeed`, a class from `rome:rome:1.0`!

Is there any known *unmanaged* (i.e. independent from Jersey HK2) centralized service aiming at resolving links or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

The main question is "where do links go in the resource" :

1. Within the resource itself, like _url fields in [github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/), quite common for json/xml
2. In HTTP "link" headers, which is probably more suitable for representations that do not allow to embed links within resource itself : images, binary files, ...

Your current jersey resource methods return a SyndFeed Object, but you should be able to :

- wrap it in another object, which allows to define a "links" section
- write a custom provider for that object type
- call existing provider that supports SyndFeed to avoid rewriting it yourself

Plus, if you make your resources inject UriInfo within that data structure, you have everything you need to write links :

- UriInfo is used to get base URL (injected by jersey)
- UriBuilder is used to resolve base/resource URL path
- "business definition" of your resource links

In this case, provider just have to "follow what's in links definition" and has no business logic. It is resource's responsability to provide such information, you can also delegate to another class of you choice.